# Hylafax server adding users with Avantfax

Tags: fax

I have two fax servers setup running Debian with Hylafax 6.0.6 and Avantfax 3.3.3. The weird problem is that one works perfectly fine when I'm trying to add users from Avantfax. The new users show up in the hosts.hfaxd file just as they should. The one I'm having an issue with doesn't do that. All of the users are added in the Avantfax database and show up in the web interface but they are not added to the hosts.hfaxd file so no one can login via a client.
None of the existing resources I've found online seem to describe this problem. There's [this post](http://sourceforge.net/p/avantfax/discussion/540878/thread/68722a4e/?limit=25#3b4a) that talks about changing a users.php file in avantfax to call faxadduser.. but my working server doesn't have that, so there must be another way it adds users to the hosts.hfaxd. The permissions on the hosts.hfaxd are correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be Avantfax requires sudo access to a few items. So I had to edit the sudoers file and add the following line:

```
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/halt, /usr/sbin/faxdeluser, /usr/sbin/faxadduser -u * -p * *
```

Now it finally works.